# Textarea size to fit all row and limit chars per row

Tags: php, jquery

I have this piece code, I am getting the `textarea` output (`$activities`) from databases. Some of the data consists of multiple rows in `textarea`. How do I display the `textarea` that can fit all the rows in the databases. Currently I am using jQuery `$('textarea').autoResize();`, it only works when entering data, it does not work when displaying data. It only displays one row with scroll bar. Also, is it possible to limit the chars for each row to 30 chars and when it hits the limit it will auto break the line? Can anyone show me an example?

php:

```
<?php

$day = 6;

for($i=1; $i<= $day ;$i++){ 
    echo "<div class='item'>";
    echo "<form class='itineraryForm' id='itineraryForm$i'  method = 'post'>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Time</th>";
    echo "<th>Activities</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<input type='text' class='i_field' name='time[]' value='$time' />";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<textarea rows='1' class='i_field$i' name='activities[]'>".$activities."</textarea>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "<input type='image' class='i_save_btn' src='img/save.png' value='SAVE' align='right'/>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click',".i_save_btn",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('inc/process.php', $(this).parents('form').serialize(), function(data) {});
    });
});
```

Comment: you can't create multiple elements with the same ID (`i_save_btn`)

Comment: `wordwrap($activities, 30, "<br />\n", TRUE ); 
//where <br /> could instead insert CR & LF`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `echo "</div>";` right after `echo "</form>";`